# Reverse DNS Error

Tags: networking, dns, ip

When performing reverse DNS queries (`dig -x <IP>`), I sometimes receive NXDOMAIN errors. From what I understand, NXDOMAIN means that the record is does not exist. If I perform a perform a typical (forward) DNS query (`dig <URL>`), the IP of the URL/host is returned without any issue. But if I take that same IP and do a reverse DNS query with it, I get an NXDOMAIN error.

As I said, this does not happen with every domain, just with a few. Are reverse records optional? Like is it up to whoever sets up the domain to decide whether or not they will answer reverse queries?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but forward and reverse DNS are entirely different queries. While they both use the DNS structure they are managed totally differently and independently. Nothing you do on a forward record will impact the reverse record in the DNS infrastructure.

Comment: For reverse DNS, it us whoever is handling reverse delegation for the (IN-ADDR.ARPA) address space for that IP.

Comment: Gotcha. So my question mainly is "why would reverse lookups fail, when a forward lookup of the domain succeeds." If I do a forward lookup and am returned an IP address, why would I not be returned the same domain name if I did a reverse lookup on said IP address. Not sure if that helps to clarify at all...

Comment: But it sounds like from what you are saying, the records for forward and reverse lookups are handled in two completely different places?

Comment: Correct - reverse and forward lookups are almost entirely unrelated in DNS. Reverse lookups have always struck me as a very creative hack of the DNS system.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now, thanks for the help!! What makes them a creative hack of the DNS system if you don't mind me asking? Just would like to hear your thoughts on it

Comment: (This is just my perception - I might be missing facts) In order to make reverse DNS a special zone - AFAIK the only on of its kind - was created called IN-ADDR.ARPA. Using this zone and creating a special record type PTR allowed lookups using the same mechanisms. Initially, I believe, a limitation of this was that it restricted subdelegation, until that was again creatively hacked around using CNAMES.  Its a hack because it appears a bit messy and bolted on to DNS. It us not intuitive or structured like forward DNS.

Comment: Yeah it definitely seems that way after reading your comments and learning a bit more about it. It doesn't feel as streamlined as forward DNS is. Really appreciate your comments and all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes reverse records are not automatically created. They have to be created and updated manually.

The reverse zone might not even be managed by the same organization that is managing the forward zone.

And even if they were, it is very common that forward DNS records are created but reverse PTR records are not. For the most part this is OK, although best practice is to keep your reverse zone in sync with the forward records.